# Can Drupal's search index external tables?

Tags: 7, search, database

Can Drupal's search system index external tables?
I have looked up how external tables can be linked to Drupal using the [Data module](https://drupal.org/project/data), [hook_views_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) etc., 
Can the content of the external tables be indexed and searched by Drupal's search system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [search api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/7) to specify your additional content. In particular you will need

- [hook_search_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_info/7)
- [hook_update_index](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_update_index/7)
- [hook_search_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7)

Comment: Is there something simpler, like a module? I am rather code phobic.